# How to loop within formulae in R

Tags: r, loops, formula

Here is the header of my data:

```
Location    Aeration    Species   Form   Method  Repeat  Days   Act    Bac   COD    Fun NH3 NO2 NO3 TN  TP  SP  SS  ChlA    TDS Sal ODO
```

Now I want to commit aov analysis for each of the data from Act to ODO, which needs formula as an argument, such as Act~Species, if no loops is used, I have to type "Act ~ Species", "Bac ~ Species", "COD ~ Species"... so I wonder if there is some way to loop the data columns in the formulae, both `for` loops and `apply` family such as `lapply` are OK. I've tried looping with indexes such as data[,8], data[8] and data[[8]] but it reported error. Could anyone tell me how to loop within R formulae? And if there's any solution provided in Hadley Wickham's `tidyverse` package such as `dplyr`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your data formatted as a tibble or df? Could you specify the error?

Comment: You could try to use a `for` loop and within a pipe use `names(.)[i]`. This should give you the name of the column you want.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague: could you share your attempts, your code, errors, some data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are stored in a dataframe named `df` and that I counted correctly such that `Act` is col 8 and `ODO` is col 22:

```
res_list <- vector(mode="list", length=105)
r <- 1
for (i in 8:22) {
for (j in 8:22) {
    if(i>j) {
        res_list[[r]] <- aov(as.formula(paste(names(df)[i], "~", names(df)[j])), data=df)
        r <- r+1
    }
}
}
```